# got confused with overriding in C++

Tags: c++, overloading

so I faced this question in an interview and got very confused about the overloading rules, could you point me to the explication at compile time.

The overloaded function:

```
int mult(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"int "; return a*b;
}

long mult(long a, long b)
{
    cout<<"long "; return a*b;
}

float mult(float a, float b)
{
    cout<<"float "; return a*b;
}
```

And then the calls:

```
long m = mult(5.2,7);
cout<<"result "<<m<<endl;
float f = mult(5,7.2);
cout<<"result "<<f<<endl;
```

What are the rules for the choice between the functions?

Comment: It seems to be overloaded, not overridden.

Comment: Functions are uniquely determined by function signature. Argument types are part of the function signature, as well as function name and certain keywords (e.g. const). Note that the return type is not part of the signature, because of runtime type casting.

Comment: right, it is overloading, I always mix both terms...

@Will Gu, so what are the rules to select one or the other function signature in my case?

Comment: I was gonna say the function is chosen by input types, thus the 3rd one. But that's wrong. I realize there's something interesting here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-30-function-overloading-and-float-in-c/

Comment: Interesting fact about double vs float... but in my example, it is even more difficult because we have one number without decimals (could be integer or long) and one number with decimals (which would be a double in our case)... so it seems the functions called here are the one with both int arguments... I still can't find the proper definition of this rule.

Comment: @WillGu well that is a double to float conversion. the `mult(int, int)` is the only one not converting one of the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a good description at [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution%20*cpp_reference*)

What is happening here is that mult is selected based on the least amount of conversions.

```
long m = mult(5.2,7);
```

`long m` is completely irrelevant. This call is `mult(double, int)` so now to find the best fit for this function the rules say find the function with the least amount of conversions applied. (See *Best viable function*).

This amounts to `mult(int, int)` only needing one conversion. All the other functions needs two implicit conversions to match.

The same argument is also true for the second call.

These rules can easily make a call ambiguous, for instance

If you added

```
float mult(int a, float b);
```

into the mix, your program doesn't compile. The call

```
float f = mult(5, 7.2);
```

Is also one implicit conversion away, the same as the `mult(int, int)` function hence ambiguous.